# check if chrome is installed on windows

Tags: python

does anyone know how I can can check if chrome is installed on windows in python?

Comment: The `chrome` executable would need to be in your environment `%PATH%` for this to work. Can you actually type `chrome` (or the other executables) in a shell and have it launch Chrome?

Comment: oh okay, I didn't know that. Is there any other simple way to check if the program is installed?

Comment: I haven't used Windows in quite a while so I can't write an answer that would be tested, but you could use the `winreg` module and check if the registry key for Chrome exists - the most common one to check now is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [wkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297696/wkl) posted I can use the winreg module and check if `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon` is registered.